# Нет звука в Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, аудио

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Звук есть только в наушниках, через динамики звука нет. Все на максимуме, почему так? Кто шарит помогите

Comment: канал speaker не пробовали включать? кнопка `m` переключает состояние mute для канала.

Answer (score 2):

Я новичок в работе с Ubuntu, но столкнулся с похожей проблемой: у меня не было звука в наушниках. 
Попробуйте выполнить следующее

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
pavucontrol
```

Затем в открывшемся окне можно выбрать устройство вывода.